# How can i get the location updates for tracking when the other device while traveling?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, location

My project is for tracking the driver from the customer device just like Uber. What i have done is I'm fetching the location data sent by the driver to the server with the help of volley library and posting it in the google maps in the user end.

I did implement the handler to periodically fetch the location updates sent by the driver. But my app was crashing giving **Unexpected response code 507** and **Unexpected response code 508**.
I just need some help as how i can acheive this or some reference would be helpful.

Below is my code.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{

    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    String newLatitude = "";
    String newLongitude = "";
    Marker marker;
    Runnable runnable;
    String schoolid, studentid;
    String LocationUrl = Constant.BASE_URL+"selectlocation/";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        schoolid = bundle.getString("ap_school_fkid");
        studentid = bundle.getString("student_fkid");

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.maps);
        if (mapFragment != null) {
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }

    }
@Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Log.d("MapsActivity", "Inside onMapReady");

        mMap = googleMap;
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, LocationUrl+schoolid+"/"+studentid+"/", new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d("MapsActivity", response);
                try {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("resp");
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        //JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        if (array.getJSONObject(i).getString("loc_latitude") != null && array.getJSONObject(i).getString("loc_longitude") != null) {
                            newLatitude = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("loc_latitude").trim();
                            newLongitude = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("loc_longitude").trim();
                            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, newLatitude + ", " + newLongitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            addmarkerToMap(newLatitude, newLongitude);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        queue.add(request);
        if (!newLatitude.isEmpty() && !newLongitude.isEmpty()) {
            Double lat = Double.parseDouble(newLatitude);
            Double lng = Double.parseDouble(newLongitude);
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("I'm Here"));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            CameraUpdate location = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 17);
            mMap.animateCamera(location);
        }
    }

    private void addmarkerToMap(String newLat, String newLng) {
        double lat = Double.parseDouble(newLat);
        double lng = Double.parseDouble(newLng);
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lng)).title("I'm Here");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        CameraUpdate location = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 17);
        mMap.animateCamera(location);
        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
            getLocation();
        }, 3000);

    }

    private void getLocation(){
        Log.d("getLocation", "Refreshed");
        mMap.clear();
        if (mMap!= null){
            if (marker == null){
                StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, LocationUrl+schoolid+"/"+studentid+"/", new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("resp");
                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                                //JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                                if (array.getJSONObject(i).getString("loc_latitude") != null && array.getJSONObject(i).getString("loc_longitude") != null) {
                                    newLatitude = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("loc_latitude").trim();
                                    newLongitude = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("loc_longitude").trim();
                                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "location is refreshed, new Latitude : "+newLatitude+", new Longitude : "+newLongitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    addmarkerToMap(newLatitude, newLongitude);
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });


                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
                queue.add(request);
                if (!newLatitude.isEmpty() && !newLongitude.isEmpty()) {
                    Double lat = Double.parseDouble(newLatitude);
                    Double lng = Double.parseDouble(newLongitude);
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("I'm Here"));
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                    CameraUpdate location = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 17);
                    mMap.animateCamera(location);
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you check this API is working on postman or not?

Comment: yes it is working and i'm getting the data for a min or so, after that the app is crashing

Comment: Can you please paste the error log or only error.

Comment: [HTTP response 507](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) means that The server is unable to store the representation needed to complete the request. And [HTTP response 508](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) means that the server detected a loop condition. You will need to discuss this with the server maintainers.

Comment: BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 508